# free transform to reshape a jpg image in illustrator cc 2015

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud, transform, free

was wondering if someone could tell me please, how to use free transform to reshape a jpg image in illustrator cc 2015?
Much Thanks G

Comment: @Manly The asker is asking about Illustrator, not Photoshop. And even though they could be easily googlable, beginner questions are welcome here, too.

Answer (score 1):

Select the image you want to transform. Hit the <kbd>E</kbd> key for the Free Transform tool. Click and drag on corners of the bounding box.